# Como personalizar un evento pusher para que solo le llegue a un determinado usuario

Tags: laravel, livewire

Estoy creando un sistema de chat con laravel livewire y pusher.

El sistema de chat permite conversaciones entre 2 usuarios y puedes tener multiples conversaciones a la vez.

Hay 2 tablas: **Conversations** y **Messages**

Mis conocimientos son un poco basicos y lo estoy desarrollando a traves de varios tutoriales.

El script de pusher que se implementa en la vista es el que viene por defecto:

```
<script>

        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('xx', {
          cluster: 'eu'
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat-channel');
        channel.bind('chat-event', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            //window.livewire.emit('mensajeRecibido', data);
        });
</script>
```

El controlador livewire que maneja el cambio de conversaciones, crea los mensajes y manda el evento es este:

```
class Chat extends Component
{
    public $you, $me, $conversationId;
    public $message;
    protected $listeners = ['mensajeRecibido'];
    public $debug =0;


    public function mensajeRecibido()
    {
        
    }
    public function conversationChange(Conversation $conversationId)
    {
        // DEFINIR NUEVAMENTE EL YOU
        $this->conversationId = $conversationId;
        $this->chat = Message::where('conversation_id', $this->conversationId->id)
             ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        $this->me = Auth::user();
        if($conversationId->id_you == $this->me->id)
        {
            $this->you = User::findOrFail($conversationId->id_me);
        } else {
            $this->you = User::findOrFail($conversationId->id_you);
        }

    }

    public function mount(?User $user)
    {
        $this->me = Auth::user();

        if($user->id){ 
            $this->you = User::find($user->id);
            $this->conversationId = Conversation::whereIn('id_me', [$this->me->id, $this->you->id])
            ->whereIn('id_you', [$this->me->id, $this->you->id])
            ->first();
        }
    }
    public function enviarMensaje()
    {
        $this->conversationId = Conversation::whereIn('id_me', [$this->me->id, $this->you->id])
                    ->whereIn('id_you', [$this->me->id, $this->you->id])
                    ->first();

        if(!$this->conversationId) // Si existe conversacion previa, solo se crea el mensaje
        {
            // Si es el primer mensaje, se crea la conversacion + el mensaje
            $this->conversationId = Conversation::create([
                'id_me' => $this->me->id,
                'id_you' => $this->you->id,
            ]);
            $this->me->messages()->create([
                'msg' => $this->message,
                'conversation_id' => $this->conversationId->id,
            ]);
        } else {
            $this->me->messages()->create([
                'msg' => $this->message,
                'conversation_id' => $this->conversationId->id,
            ]);
        }
        event(new ChatSendMessage($this->you));
        $this->message = '';
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $this->debug++;
        $chat = Message::where('conversation_id', optional($this->conversationId)->id)
         ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('livewire.front-end.chat.chat', ['chat' => $chat]);
    }
```

Funciona de la siguiente manera:

1. Al crear el mensaje manda el evento a la vista
2. Todas las personas que están conectadas al chat reciben el evento y
   por consiguiente se renderiza su pagina con una consulta a la base
   de datos innecesaria.

El objetivo es que solo la persona que tiene que recibir el mensaje dispare el evento o que solo la persona que recibe el mensaje renderice la pagina.

Ya que si hay 300 personas en el chat con diferentes conversaciones a todas se les va a renderizar la pagina en cada mensaje

De que manera lo puedo plantear?

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de crear tu clase notification o event, debes agregar un channel autorizado para que este pueda ser ingresado solo por los usuarios que requieras.

Esta parte de la documentación podría darte una idea [Channels autorizados](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#authorizing-channels)

Comment: Gracias gaidyjg! Voy a mirarlo